# SIR Models - interpretation (epidemiology) - help!

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, maple

I am doing a project on modelling the spread of diseases and am using a SIR (susceptible, infected and recovered) model to do so. I need help interpreting this plot:

[image]

What does this plot say about an epidemic of a population?

any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what it says is the at the worse time, around 10% of the populations will be infected. More importantly, the asymptotic solution shows that "only" 60% of people will be affected which implies that 40% of the population will never get sick.

All plots show the proportion of your population divided into three classes at any time $t>0$.

Finally, you can see that after approximately 3 days (assuming $t$ is in days), your infection has already almost disappeared as it is not able to transfer to anyone else.

If there's any aspect I didn't cover and you want more explanation about, feel free to comment.

Comment: how many people are infected?

Comment: $I(t)$ is the proportion of the infected people so at any time $t > 0$, $P\times I(t)$ where $P$ is your total populations is the number of people being infected.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to notice is that the number of suspectibles is $>0$ even when the disease is dying out (the number of infected goes to zero)

So the epidemic ends because of lack of infected people and not because we ran out of suspectible indivuals.